# Allow Read only users to Attach files to records

Tags: case, record-access-level

If a profile has read-only access to Case records. Is there any (easy) way that the user can add files to Attachments folder on the case record with their Read-only access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a profile has read-only access to Case records, then a user can not add files to Attachment folder inside Salesforce since an option "new" in the detail side for Attachment section to add files might not be visible at all if user is not the owner of that case. Of course, the user cannot edit the case at all even though the "edit" button is visible.

It may be possible using Data Loader but never tried.

Answer (score 0):

This is not 'easy', but you could build a Visualforce page that would allow users to attach Attachments to the Case object.  This would work because Apex code will ignore the read-only security and do whatever you want.