# User assigned with Read-only permission set group can upload files

Tags: apex, permission-sets, files, admin, fileupload

In my org there is a permission set group called `ReadOnlyFundingOpportunity` with the following permission sets:

- ReadOnlyFundingOpp on the FundingOpportunity object.

I assumed a user assigned with this permission set group should not be able to upload Files. However, I found out during testing that all the fields were read-only but I could still upload files to a record. This user is not assigned with other permission sets.

I'm confused because I found conflicting info

**Read and Edit permissions are required** (It's for Attachments but I thought there's little difference between the 2?)

[Allow Read only users to Attach files to records](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/34759/allow-read-only-users-to-attach-files-to-records)

[Insufficient privileges when uploading attachment to record](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/199294/insufficient-privileges-when-uploading-attachment-to-record)

**Read and Edit permission sets are not required**

https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdaSMUAZ/controlling-permission-on-notes-attachments-irrespective-of-objective-perm

[Read-only permissions on Files](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/261783/read-only-permissions-on-files/261784#261784)

Is there a setting for this or an Apex-based solution?

Comment: You could always add a Custom Permission to the PS and test that in Apex on a trigger on ContentDocumentLink.

Comment: What do I put in the custom permission? I already has read-only for the object

Comment: the custom permission can be tested in apex to see if the running user has that permission - and then the trigger can do addError if they try and upload a file